# Internal CDN and setting up subdomain to increase maximum parallel connections

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, performance, cdn

I've heard that browsers can have around maximum of 6 parallel connections per domain at a time.

So I decided to have another subdomain "cdn." then use mod_rewrite to point to media folder then change image references pointing to this "cdn." for articles in the database.

Will this increase the speed of the site since it's increasing parallel connections to about 12 now?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your server can handle the extra work load, then yes. You are essentially decreasing the overall latency of the page.